# How to move .env file into build folder with tsconfig

Tags: typescript, environment-variables

How does one move files that are not `.ts` or `.js` files from the root directory to the build directory using `tsconfig.json`? I don't see any specific options for it. It would be good to move any non `.js` or `.ts` files

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpiling typescript to javascript is done by the `tsc` executable (or using the typescript library directly) with the configuration in `tsconfig`, it's not supposed to handle general tasks of bundling/packaging.

If you need to perform additional tasks with your build, like copying files, you can:

- Use `npm` run scripts to call `tsc` then copy files
- Create a shell script
- Use a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/)
- Write your own builder using the typescript library to compile ts

For simple projects, start with npm or shell script. If your code is targeting browsers you will probably need a bundler anyway, so your file copying will be part of the bundling process.

Comment: That makes sense. I was thinking tsconfig might have something but this approach works well too.